Our BIP RTF template sum is not working properly
I need your help in my RTF template that has a sum for every each segments.

I added the field in the cell, set the Calculation to Sum and checked the Grouping.
Generated the report and it's giving "0.00" in value instead of 5,149.999.96 (DEBITS Column)
PDF generated report

Here's the report layout:
enter image description here
enter image description here
I would appreciate any help. I'm not sure if the sum is already not working in the BIP reports or I just misconfigured something in the template.
Thank you in advance.

I already tried clearing the Repeating Groups but the sum is still not working.
I tried unchecking the Grouping, but it's giving incorrect sum.

My expectation is it would sum the values in a column.

Try it like this:
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ENTERED_DEBITS)"/>

